# Mixed-model or not? Case-study in R

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, mixed-model

I performed some observations of [clownfishes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphiprioninae). For each individual fish (each observation), I recorded the anemone species where it lives, the size of the anemonea and the size of the fish (and many other things but we'll forget them for the purpose of this question). In total I have 8 fishes and 7 anemones. It represents the total number of species present in the sampling area.

I want to know if the **size of the anemonae** correlates with the **size of the fish**. But I have to decorrelate the **fish species** and the **anemonea species** from this analysis as both are maybe correlated with the **size of the fish**. What model should I run on R?

May I run the following...

```
aov(fish.size ~ factor(fish.species) + factor(anemone.species) + anemone.size)
```

and record only the p.value for the `anemone.size`?

Or should I use a mixed-model-effect?

```
lmer(fish.size ~ anemone.size + 1 | factor(fish.species) + 1 | 
   factor(anemone.species))
```

or something else?..

Comment: How many fish species and anemone species do you have in total?

Comment: @JakeWestfall 8 fishes, 7 anemones. It represents the totality of all species of clownfishes and anemones present in the sampling area. I updated my post to add this info. Thanks for your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either approach would probably be fine. I would probably go with the random effects model for the sake of the economy of parameters (4 total parameters instead of 15 total parameters), although the number of levels for the random effects is a little on the small side. As long as you have a reasonable number of observations within each fish species and anemone species I think it should be fine. Try it and see. Note that both of these models assume that the relationship between anemone.size and fish.size is constant across fish species and anemone species.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask a second question directly in this comment? Does it make sense to make a backward elimination on my aov() model? Or is it better not to do such things when some variables are used in order to get rid of some variation between the variables of interest as I do?

Comment: I think in this context (as, in my opinion, in most contexts) a backward selection procedure would not make sense. If the fish.species and anemone.species variables account for some variation, the backward selection procedure will favor keeping them, but if they don't account for much variation at all, then by definition it won't matter much whether you keep them or leave them in the model anyway! So you can't really go too wrong with just leaving them in regardless of what the backward selection procedure decides.